# Wordpress .htaccess rewrite rule to add a variable to a given page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site that is already using the .htaccess file to display clean URLS such as example.com/post-name

The wordpress .htaccess file contains the following code normally to do this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My problem is that I have special page that has a conditional statement in it based on a variable I want to pass through the URL. This URL actually works if I type it in the browser and functions properly: http://example.com/dir/?var=var-value

What I want to do is make this url clean by adding a new redirect rule to make the url look like this: http://example.com/dir/var-value. What I have added to the file is below:

```
RewriteRule ^dir/([^/]*)$ /dir/?var=$1 [L]
```

I don't have a good understanding of regex especially in a .htaccess file and I have not been able to figure this out. If I add this redirect and then type in the appropriate url I just get a page not found error. I have already tried moving my rule to different locations within the file and I get the same result.

Additional information is that "dir" is an actual page created by the wordpress admin, I assume there is some conflict here. I did find this page on wordpress that could be helpful http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule however I can't get it to work, I don't know if I put this in my functions.php or in my custom template file.

I am using a child theme of the genesis framework that I created.

Comment: So I have the page rewritting now appropriately, but I can't access the variable. I know that you are not supposed to be able to access the variable via $_GET and I tried using $wp_query->query_vars['var'] but this does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

As per your linked doc can you try this:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^dir/([^/]+)/?','dir?var=$matches[1]','top');
```

Comment: Well part of my question was where do I put this code? In my custom page file or my functions file?

Comment: I believe this goes in function file.